# How to display RTSP stream on web page without using ActiveX

Tags: android, ios, activex, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to display an RTSP stream without using an ActiveX like VLC or Quicktime.
I need this because I want to display it in an Android or iOS web page and not openning their own player.

I'm open to all suggestions as it's something that needs to get done.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
VideoView vd; 
vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));  
vd.requestFocus();
vd.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but actually i'm developping a web site for computer with Zend Framework and I want to play the video as well on computer as on smartphone. Also I don't know where I can put your code.

Comment: you can look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193684/how-to-play-html5-video-on-a-webview-android

Comment: The problem is i would like to display a RTSP stream ans the only way I know is to use an ActiveX and the smartphone's browser can't use it.

Comment: no you can use videoview to show rtsp on androd it is possible

Comment: sry i expressed myself badly i want to know if i put it in a .html, .php or .js

Comment: this code is for android , you can put videoview your xml layout and then set it in your code like my answer it is working